# Twitter Stream API delivers tweets without the key words in text

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, spyder, twitterapi-python

I started extracting tweets via the streaming API. However, I noticed that some tweets do not contain the key words which I defined in the text, however, there are also tweets that are e.g. a reply to tweets that contain such a key word.

How can I ensure that only those tweets that contain the word in the text are considered?

I'm really thankful for any help!

```
#Load packages and define parameters
import tweepy
key_words = ["xx"]

class TwitterStreamer():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def stream_tweets(self, twitter_data_title, key_words):
        listener = StreamListener(twitter_data_title)
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret_token)
        stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener)
        stream.filter(track=key_words)


class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, twitter_data_title):
        self.fetched_tweets_filename = twitter_data_title

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            print(data)
        
            with open(self.fetched_tweets_filename, 'a') as tf:
                tf.write(data)
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data %s" % str(e))
        return True
    
    def on_exception(self, exception):
        print('exception', exception)
        stream_tweets(twitter_data_title, key_words)    

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
    
def stream_tweets(twitter_data_title, key_words):
    listener = StreamListener(twitter_data_title)
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret_token)
    stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, listener)
    stream.filter(track=key_words)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    twitter_streamer = TwitterStreamer()
    twitter_streamer.stream_tweets(twitter_data_title, key_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/basic-stream-parameters):

> The text of the Tweet and some entity fields are considered for matches. Specifically, the text attribute of the Tweet, expanded_url and display_url for links and media, text for hashtags, and screen_name for user mentions are checked for matches.

So, if you only want Tweets with text that matches your supplied key words, you will have to remove those tweets whose text does not contain your supplied key words yourself.